# Prove, in ZFC, that there is a property $P$ such that neither $P$ nor $\neg P$ determines a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC, some properties are such that either it or its negation determines a set. For example, the property $x \in x$ determines the empty set. Also, the property $x=x$, while it does not determine a set, its negation $x \neq x$ does, which is the empty set again. I am looking for a first-order property $P(x)$ in one variable such that ZFC proves that (1) there is no set that contains all and only the $x$'s such that $P(x)$, and (2) nor is there a set that contains all and only the $x$'s such that $\neg P(x)$. I also want the proof that neither $P$ nor $\neg P$ determines a set. It does not have to be a formal proof, I just want an informal proof, a human-readable argument of my claim.

Comment: Did you try to find one yourself? "Is an ordinal" does the job. So does "Has exactly one element," "Has exactly two elements," and countless others.

Comment: ZFC does not allow you to use properties on their own to determine sets; ZFC does not have an Axiom of Comprehension, it has an Axiom of separation. Given a property, **and a set $A$**, you can construct the set $\{x\in A\mid P(x)\}$, but you cannot justify the existence of a set simply by writing $\{x\mid P(x)\}$. Your question is misguided and built on an incorrect foundation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're reading the OP uncharitably. It's perfectly common to speak of a formula determining a set in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that the class of things satisfying that formula is indeed a set. And indeed the body of the question is careful to explain precisely what is being looked for. The OP's question is not misguided or built on an incorrect foundation (although it is trivial).